# How does D7100 bracketing work?

Tags: bracketing, nikon-d7100

I use Raw + JPEG basic and aperture priority to shoot photos. I tried to turn on AE bracketing or ADL bracketing with 3 or 5 frames. But I never see the camera produced 3 or 5 images when I browse photo in camera or download the files to PC.

How can I exactly to make it work?

Comment: Page 133 of your manual answers this question.

Comment: Thanks for the head up, I checked manual again, it does not specify very clearly I have to press shutter multiple times as Wayne explained below.

Comment: You didn't check it again very well. The top of page 136 states "In other modes, one shot will be taken each time the shutter-release button is pressed". Just read the manual. It will help you I promise. You replied to my comment so fast you wouldn't have even had time to read the section in question.

Comment: @dpollitt, it is my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in single-shot mode, you'll need to press the shutter release 3 or 5 times. It doesn't automatically shoot all of the shots with one shutter press.

(Which has bitten me a couple of times when I forgot to shut AE bracketing back off and ended up with puzzlingly inconsistently-exposed shots afterwards.)

Comment: It is very good to know. Since I have to press shutter multiple times, if I don't use tripod I may produce images slightly off from previous one. So do most HDR software be able to handle it when they are merged?

Comment: @hardywang - Yes most HDR software can correct for slight movement between frames, but the best results will come with a tripod. You could also just switch the Shooting mode from single shot to continuous before the capture.

Comment: @dpollitt yeah, it is a good suggestion. But it is just inconvenient that I have to change shooting mode back and forth. I really wish the camera could automatically take multiple photos just like continuously shooting mode once I turn on bracketing.

Comment: @hardywang: There is a Bracket Burst function (or similar name) that you can assign to a button that might help. I believe you hold that button down and press the shutter and it fires off like continuously shooting mode, if you're bracketing.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the self-timer, and set the number of shots to 3 (or 5), then press the shutter release, it will take the whole bracket.  If you can hold the camera steady and put up with the minimum delay of the self timer, you'll probably get better results since you don't have to press the shutter release repeatedly.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, I will give it a try once I get home.

Comment: OK, I tried MikeW's answer, and it works like a charm. So there are at least three ways to get a multi-exposure burst with auto bracketing. I'm still going to use my corded remote release for exposures over 30 seconds, but the self timer is the bomb for most shots.

Answer (score 2):

I accompanied a pro photographer on a shoot at one of my projects. His Canon had a function which burst exposed 5 bracketed shots. Having just purchased a D7100, I knew I had to find a way to do the same thing with my new camera. Long story short, and many experiments later, you can either press the shutter release once for each of the bracketed exposures (including with a wired or wireless remote), or, if you set the interval timer and activate it while in bracket mode, it will expose the 3 or 5 frames automatically in burst fashion. A third approach, and the one I plan to use, is to set my wired remote release set for the same number of exposures as the auto bracket, a 1 second time between exposures, and zero duration and zero delay. This exposes the correct number of frames automatically, and keeps my hand off the camera while doing so. Since I do a lot of architecture and landscape photography, I see this as the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The lower ring on the mode selector  ( top left from the back)  has

S for single
Cl for Continuous slow speed shooting.
Ch for Continuous high speed shooting.

When you are in bracketing mode, on either the slow or high speed setting it changes from continuous to just the number of shots selected by the bracketing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Set Continues (L or H) and set BKT for 3 (or 5, or 7). You will have 3 (or 5, or 7) BKT pictures. The simplest way.